# About Android webview file upload

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview in android app, the webview will load a html page contains file upload control.I override the "openFileChooser" function, so I can select file in webview,but after I choose file and return to webview, the file name while change to url-encoded format(If the file name isn't ascii character) ?

[image: First step]

[image: After choose]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can (or should) do here.

The operating system handles these things, i.e. placing the selected file in the `value` attribute of the `<input type="file">`.

But there's nothing wrong with these URL-encoded names. You shouldn't rely on the filenames from the client side, anyway.

What you should use is only the file's content and maybe its size and extension as reported.